# Terminate statement if no result received in 10 min

Tags: powershell

I am running below statement in my script, the target folder has files in lacks (around 6 lack). Some time the statement struck, how do I terminate the statement if no result for more than 10 min.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Folder -Include $Etxn |
         Where-Object {
             $_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite" -and
             $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the statement as a [job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a timeout.

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
           Get-ChildItem $Folder -Include $Etxn |
           Where-Object {
               $_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite" -and
               $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false
           }
       }
Wait-Job -Job $job -Timeout 600 | Out-Null
$Files = Receive-Job -Job $job
Remove-Job -Job $job
```